# Xamarin.Forms: Getting the position from a tapped Image inside a Listview

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to save the position of the tapped Image inside my ListView. It's a Tapped event so it doesn't count as ItemSelected.

It's a simple ListView and each element has a "star" image to mark as favourite. It could work browse the ListView and get the positions where the Image is the "filled star" on the `OnDisappearing()` saving them on an array for example.

**ListView Structure:**

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>

                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

                <Image x:Name="imageFavourite"
                         Source="starBorder.png"
                         Scale="0.5"
                         HorizontalOptions="Center"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="imageFavourite_Tapped"
                                              NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try to add a `CommandParameter` to the `TapGestureRecognizer`, like this: `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"`. You should now be able to access the object in the list that was tapped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for your time @GeraldVersluis.

I realized I have lots of things to learn yet and it's pending work for me learning how to use CommandParameter because I know nothing about Command Interface.

I finally got it using this little trick:

    `ViewCell viewCell = imageFavourite.Parent.Parent as ViewCell;`
    `mySelectedObject = viewCell.BindingContext as MyObject;`

   `var myList = listView.ItemsSource as List<MyObject>;`
    `var index =   myList.IndexOf(mySelectedObject);`

I know it isn't the proper way but it's the only thing I was able to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to get the command parameters working with casting the binding instead of the way that you're doing it.

Here is the image xaml set up:

```
<Image x:Name="DeleteImage"
  Source="ic_delete.png"
  Margin="25,0,0,0">
  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
   <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Tapped="DeleItem" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Here is the C# backend for the tap gesture recognizer (note: this is using a TappedEventArgs not EventArgs!):

```
async void DeleItem(object sender, TappedEventArgs args)
{
    var row = (YOUR-OBJECT-CAST)args.Parameter;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write($"Row clicked: (your object) {row.ID}");
}
```

Comment: `Eventhandler 'DeleteItem' with correct signature not found in type "mypage"` is the error I get when I try this